# how to determine if I have the latest security update or not by powershell?

Tags: powershell, exchange, email-server, command-line-interface, windows-server-core

I'm a beginner to exchange server and powershell, I'm working on Exchange server (on-premise), how can I determine if I have the latest updates, security update, version of windows server (core) and exchange server, or not, so I have to update it? (by powershell).

Thanks in advance

Comment: The answer is right in the Microsoft docs on patching server core. Easily found using your favorite search engine

Comment: Hi, it's been a while, any update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Exchange Server Health Checker Script on GitHub to see if server up to date or not:
https://github.com/dpaulson45/HealthChecker#download

1. On your server, open EMS and then open the folder where you’ve downloaded the HealthChecker.ps1 PowerShell script. Now Run following command

.\HealthChecker.ps1
[image]

2. This script will list all the security vulnerabilities that you need to patch. If you see multiple vulnerabilities, or if your Exchange server is compromised then you need to use EOMT. You can refer following links:
   [Microsoft Exchange Remote Code Execution Vulnerability Flaws and Their Fixes](https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/microsoft-exchange-remote-code-execution-vulnerability-flaws-and-fixes/)

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/exchange-health-checker-has-a-new-home/ba-p/2306671

https://petri.com/understanding-exchange-server-updates-and-the-process-to-patching

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there doesn't seem to be any script or commands which can detect if the current versions of Exchange and windows server are latest.

The available methods are to manually get the current versions, and then compare with the **[microsoft docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/new-features/build-numbers-and-release-dates?view=exchserver-2019)**:

1 Navigate to the following location: **Control Panel** -> **Uninstall a program** & **View installed updates**

[image]

[image]

2 Run the following commands as administrator in Exchange PowerShell:

```
$ExchangeServers = Get-ExchangeServer | Sort-Object Name
ForEach ($Server in $ExchangeServers)
{
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server.Name -ScriptBlock { Get-Command Exsetup.exe | ForEach-Object { $_.FileversionInfo } }
}
```

[image]

[image]

---

Or you can navigate to the following location: **`Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Update\Change settings`**, and check the checkbox "**Give me updates for other Microsoft products when I update Windows**" so that you will get the latest SU versions of Exchange server and patch versions of windows server when checking for updates:

[image]